# jquery does not become available in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

the following works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, but of course not in MSIE 8 or MSIE 8-compatibility view:

```
<html>
<head><title>saffds</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">      alert($);
</script>
</head>
<body>afdskakj</body></html>
```

MSIE claims that $ is undefined, whereas the other browsers display the $-function of jQuery.

I have tried deleting all temporary files and restarting MSIE, setting the internet options > security > local internet to "very low" but it does not help.

Jquery from ajax.googleapis.com used to work for me a few days ago, but now I have no idea what changed to break this.

What causes this to fail?

Thanks,

-- Edit: I have tested the following, which also does not work except for Link1 which does not depend on jQuery and otherfile.js' alert which also does not depend on jQuery.

```
<html>
<head><title>saffds</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="otherfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('I love jQuery!');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>afdskakj
<a href="" onclick="alert('Hello world')">Link1</a>
<a href="">Link2</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('I love jQuery!');
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
  });
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

the contents of otherfile.js is simply:

```
alert("otherfile");
```

Comment: Your code works for me as-is. I suspect it may just be a transitory connectivity issue or a problem with your IE installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was resolved by resetting MSIE as described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318378

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if that solved the problem. As I said, there wasn't anything intrinsically wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jQuery file is not downloaded yet. Check the chapter "hello jquery" in [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).

You need to have to wait till everything is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
  });
});
```

Comment: While this is the recommended way to launch jQuery stuff, it won't help in this case: if `$` is not defined, neither will `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Didn't work. MSIE still complains about the $ that 'object expected'

Comment: @Alvaro: Yes, you are right. I didn't look at all the details. I was assuming that the DOM is not ready yet and that this was the reason why it did not start.